# stunnel certificate verification

Tags: ssl, openssl, pki, stunnel

I am trying to setup stunnel with certificate verification. I have put `verify = 1` in `stunnel.conf`.

I generated a certificate for STunnel server and client and signed with CA (CA setup in lab) :

```
openssl req -out stunnel.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout stunnel.key
scp stunnel.csr root@<CA IP Address>:/etc/pki/CA/csr/
openssl ca -extensions v3_ca -days 3650 -in csr/stunnel.csr -out certs/stunnel.pem
cat stunnel.key >> stunnel.pem
```

But when I use this cert I get error:

```
2014.05.07 17:01:56 LOG4[8343:140373923505920]: VERIFY ERROR: depth=1, error=unable to get issuer certificate: /C=US/ST=California/O=Org/OU=OrgUnit TLM/CN=CAHost
2014.05.07 17:01:56 LOG3[8343:140373923505920]: SSL_accept: 140890B2: error:140890B2:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:no certificate returned
2014.05.07 17:01:56 LOG5[8343:140373923505920]: Connection reset: 0 bytes sent to SSL, 0 bytes sent to socket
```

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: The `unable to get issuer certificate` means something does not trust the CA. I don't know what generated the log file, so its not clear to me what is not trusting your private CA.

Comment: You can test your new cert with `openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port> -CAfile <your CA>`. If it finishes with `Verify OK (0)`, then everything is working properly.

Answer (score -3):

> What is going wrong here ?

The error is 0x140890B2:

```
SSL_accept: 140890B2: error:140890B2:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:no certificate returned
```

The error string from OpenSSL is "no certificate returned".

If you supply the client certificate, then the problem will likely go away.